# services should be autonomous.Confusing words

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, architecture

wonder if somebody can clarify "services should be autonomous",
I have looked in stackoverflow and google and I get a lot of theory but not pratical example.

It seems is more something to aim for rather than something that is achievable.

let me give you an example:

I have Customer WCF service so I do

- MyCompany.Services.CustomerContract (dll)

  ```
  ICustomerContract
  CustomerDto
  ICustomerRepository
  ```
- MyCompany.Services.CustomerService(dll)

  ```
  CustomerWcfService   
  CustomerDomain  
  CustomerRepository
  ```

In order to keep it autonomous and instead of having another dll for domain and repository I have all of them within the `CustomerService` (dll) so is truly autonomous/

In the past I used to have the following dlls

- MyCompany.Core(dll)
- MyCompany.Entities(dll)
- MyCompany.Domain(dll)
- MyCompany.Services (dll)
- MyCompany.Repository (dll)

And group all the entities together all domains together,

However it strikes to me that however it's simpler it breaks the tenets of SOA

Any advice on how to structure a wcf project?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always taken this to mean the service does not rely on outside logic.

For example, if this service allowed customer data to be saved - to be autonomous that service must encapsulate the business rules and validation that assert a customer is valid before committing it, rather than rely on the client to take care of it.

Encapsulating the whole service in its own DLL is not necessary in my opinion. The seperation your pattern gives you is a desirable feature and provided functionality is presented by your wcf service alone, it doesn't present any issue and in fact better lends itself to dependency injection, reuse, unit testing and mocking.

One final point, your pattern suggests a data store which is external to your service code. If the argument against seperation is that you lose autonomy- then surely a reliance on a storage layer or in fact an underlying framework or operating system also prevents autonomy.

Comment: @kidshaw.Thanks for your reply.what pattern do you use to structure a wcf service?Any pointers to some samples I can download as a reference or starting point?I thought that by including the dal and business within the service than it's truly autonomous no?

Comment: As I say, the autonomous aspect comes from the logic and business rules being encapsulated in your service - and of course not redistributing your dlls. How you seperate these layers across assemblies is your preference. The seperation you included earlier in your question is as logical as any. Plus, if you later decide you want to present your service via a different technology, such as WEB API, you've got a load of your code already separated.